# Method that performs operations inside an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

I have an array a=[1, 2, 'N']. I would like a method to do if a[2] = 'N', increase a[1] by 1.
I tried this:

```
def change
  if self[2] == 'N'
    self[1] += 1
  end
end

a.change
```

It gives me an error: undefined method `change' for [1, 2, "N"]:Array

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing an `end` for your `def`.

Comment: The `end` was there I edited the question

Comment: Where do you define your method?

Comment: I have a class with all my methods. `change` is called in another method `move` just below in the same class. `move` is called in another file.

Comment: That change seems to be very specific and not suitable for arrays in general. So why not use a custom class instead of a generic array?

Comment: Oh wait, that array values denote position and heading, right? `[1, 2, 'N']` means x = 1, y = 2, heading = north. And `change` is supposed to read the heading and apply the corresponding coordinate change, i.e. `N` should result in an incremented y value. In that case, you should definitely create your own class.

Comment: Exactly! I used the method form Surya and added it to my class with all the other methods. If I create a separate class I can't call the methods in my main file anymore, even with `require_relative 'file'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the array as an argument:

```
def change(a)
  if a[2] == 'N'
    a[1] += 1
  end
end

change(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

a = [1, 2, 'N']

```
puts a

class Array
    def change()
      if self[2] == 'N'
        self[1] += 1
      end
    end
end

a.change

puts a
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't monkey patch Ruby's core classes.